# Как сделать автоматическую перезагрузку страницы при ее изменении на сервере?

Tags: node.js, вёрстка, gulp, автоматизация

Когда верстаю страницу или пишу ее логику на js, я использую gulp connect.reload(). При сохранении файла галп видит, что файлы изменились и перезагружает страницу браузера. Это удобно.

Но когда это не просто верстка страницы или элемента, а разработка компонента, зависящего от данных с сервера, мне уже не удастся следить за страницей, открытой на локальном компе. Мне приходится после каждого изменения заливать файлы на сервер (либо это будет происходить автоматически с помощью галпа), а затем открывать адрес моего сайта и нажимать ctrl + f5. Это не удобно.

Сервер на ноде.

Есть ли какой-то способ это автоматизировать? Как эту проблему решаете вы?

Comment: а какой сервер используется?

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.